# Modal dialog not taking up full screen on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios-simulator

This is a really silly problem, but for the life of me I can't figure this out. As you can see in the screenshot, my modal window is not taking up the full window height on the iOS6 simulator with retina4 display.

http://www.usareststops.com/images/ios6_screenshot.png

My deployment target is iOS 5. My controller has a "Help" button who's action is set to another controller on the storyboard. It's segue has a "Modal" style and "Cover Vertical" transition. The animation works fine, but stops too soon as you can see in the photo.

Everything works fine with the iOS6 simulator except this dialog. The dialog works fine on the other simulators as well as my iPhone4.Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I knew it was silly. I had the autosizing properties wrong for my toolbar and for the scrollview. The toolbar had the left, right and bottom struts set. I changed it to left, top, and right and that bumped the toolbar to the top of the window. Then I had to set the scroll view to stretch top to bottom. Everything is working now.

Comment: You should accept your own answer.  It's worth some points.  :-)

Comment: Thanks @BlackFrog, I apparently have to wait 2 more days!